# Print lines according to the difference between values of the same column

Tags: awk

I have been trying for a while to filter a text document.

I have file like this:

```
a score=2910 EG2=0 E=0  
s MJUT01042700.1 17232 3459 + 53939
s scaffold1|size190226 11711 3461 + 190226

a score=1427 EG2=0 E=0  
s MJUT01011585.1 1110178 1852 + 1659926
s scaffold1|size190226 96228 1834 + 190226

a score=1136 EG2=0 E=0  
s MJUT01033992.1 44701 1369 + 67673
s scaffold1|size190226 96715 1347 + 190226

a score=1074 EG2=0.02 E=0  
s MJUT01027223.1 115853 1482 + 196715
s scaffold1|size190226 140742 1471 + 190226

a score=1060 EG2=0 E=0.3  
s MJUT01027223.1 192518 1484 + 196715
s scaffold1|size190226 140742 1471 + 190226
```

I want to keep the triplet of lines if, for each triplet, the difference of the 6th column (the last one) between the third and the second one is positive.

For example with the first triplet : 190226 - 53939 > 0, so I print the whole triplet of lines.

I tried several things but it seems I have trouble to deal with line jumps. My command returns nonsense :).

I'm absolutely not used to awk, I apologize if the command below is ugly ... :

```
awk -F " " '{
    l1=$1; l2=$2; l3=$3; l4=$4; # get line with score, Eg and E
    getline;
    ll1=$1; ll2=$2; ll3=$3; ll4=$4; ll5=$5; ll6=$6; # get "MJUT..." line
    getline;

    if ($6-ll6 >= 0) # Compare values between "MJUT..." line and "scaffold" line
        print l1, l2, l3, l4;
        print ll1, ll2, ll3, ll4, ll5, ll6;
        print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6;
        print "";

    getline; # Jump to next score line
    }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Apparently, it works when I put my if statements between '{...}', but I have been told it's not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special record separator `''` (empty string) to split records on empty lines, then check if the last field is larger than the 10th field:

```
$ awk -v RS='' '$NF > $10' infile
a score=2910 EG2=0 E=0  
s MJUT01042700.1 17232 3459 + 53939
s scaffold1|size190226 11711 3461 + 190226
a score=1136 EG2=0 E=0  
s MJUT01033992.1 44701 1369 + 67673
s scaffold1|size190226 96715 1347 + 190226
```

Comment: `awk -v RS= '$NF>$10'`

Comment: @karakfa I knew there was a shorter one hidden in there, but my brain stopped short ;)